# Redirecting http://www.server.com:portX to http://subdomain.server.com

Tags: redirect, port-forwarding, httpd.conf

I've got outdated requests coming into a custom port (2104) on my server.

http://www.server.com:portX

I've now setup my machine to handle those requests at:

http://subdomain.server.com:80

But how can I redirect old requests coming in like that? (through httpd magic)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Apache config, you can make a VirtualHost for the port 2104 with a redirect to the proper URL.

```
Listen *:2104

<VirtualHost *:2104>
   Redirect 301 / http://subdomain.server.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

This is assuming your browser can follow redirects. If you need something fancy like a proxy, that's a different story.

Comment: @lunixbochs - I already have a Listen MYIPADDRESS:80 up top - what do i do?

Comment: You can listen to more than one port. For example, enabling SSL requires you to add a Listen 443 directive. I dropped this at the very end of a working httpd.conf on a server, restarted apache, and it just worked. You just need to make sure you don't have anything else running on port 2104 on that server anymore (because it'd conflict).

Comment: @lunixbochs - so I just add another line just before the VirtualHost as you specified and it should work fine...?

Comment: The exact text I specified should be all you need.

Comment: Hmm @lunixbochs - there are some additional factors. The URL being accessed is like: http://server.com:2104/sessionadapter.por?id=723491 . This should be redirected to: http://alpha.server.com:80/sessionadapter.por?id=723491

Comment: (sorry to bother you!)

Comment: throw a trailing slash on the redirect (I edited my answer to show that) and your requested behavior should work properly.

Comment: You can also use "redirect 301" to specify a permanent instead of temporary redirect (this sounds like a permanent case)